# How to show tooltip on a point click in swift

Tags: swift, graphics, tooltip, line, point

I am drawing the lines using the following code. The line edges have dots and i want to show the tooltip when user click on the end dots. 
The code snippet is below,

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
      UIColor.brownColor().set()
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    //CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 5)
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 50, 50)
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context,100, 200)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    // now add the circle on at the line edges

        var point = CGPoint(x:50 , y:50)
        point.x -= 5.0/2
        point.y -= 5.0/2
        var circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 5.0,height: 5.0)))
        circle.fill()

        point = CGPoint(x:100 , y:200)
        point.x -= 5.0/2
        point.y -= 5.0/2
        circle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize(width: 5.0,height: 5.0)))
        circle.fill()

    }
```

It is currently displaying the following image,
[image]

and i want to show the tooltip like below,
[image]

Does anybody have an idea how will i recognise that this particular dot is clicked and also how will i show the tooltip.
I am looking for a solution in swift.

Comment: Do you solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a struct to hold points you have to touch, and the text to show:

```
struct TouchPoint {
    var point: CGPoint // touch near here to show a tooltip
    var tip: String // show this text when touched
}
```

then in the `UIView` subclass where you define `drawRect`, make somewhere to keep them:

```
var touchPoints: [TouchPoint] = [] // where we have to touch and what tooltip to show
```

`drawRect` can be called many times, so start fresh each time:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    touchPoints = []
    // ...
    // add a touchPoint for every place to touch
    touchPoints.append(TouchPoint(point: point, tip: "point 1"))
}
```

You need to detect taps on the UIView, so add a gesture recognizer by changing its initialisation:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    // standard init for a UIView wiht an added gesture recognizer
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector("touched:")))
}
```

then you need a method to see whether touches are near touchpoints, and to show the right tooltip:

```
func touched(sender:AnyObject) {
    let tapTolerance = CGFloat(20) // how close to the point to touch to see tooltip
    let tipOffset = CGVector(dx: 10, dy: -10) // tooltip offset from point
    let myTag = 1234 // random number not used elsewhere
    guard let tap:CGPoint = (sender as? UITapGestureRecognizer)?.locationInView(self) else { print("touched: failed to find tap"); return }
    for v in subviews where v.tag == myTag { v.removeFromSuperview() } // remove existing tooltips
    let hitPoints:[TouchPoint] = touchPoints.filter({CGPointDistance($0.point, to: tap) < tapTolerance}) // list of tooltips near to tap
    for h in hitPoints { // for each tooltip to show
        let f = CGRect(origin: h.point+tipOffset, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 20)) // fixed size label :-(
        let l = UILabel(frame: f)
        l.tag = myTag // just to be able to remove the tooltip later
        l.text = h.tip // draw the text
        addSubview(l) // add the label to the view
    }
}

func CGPointDistanceSquared(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { return (from.x - to.x) * (from.x - to.x) + (from.y - to.y) * (from.y - to.y) }

func CGPointDistance(from: CGPoint, to: CGPoint) -> CGFloat { return sqrt(CGPointDistanceSquared(from, to: to)) }
```

and that incidentally uses a new version of the `+` operator to perform vector addition on `CGPoint`:

```
func +(left: CGPoint, right: CGVector) -> CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: left.x+right.dx, y: left.y+right.dy) }
```

and that works OK for me. Extra tweaks would be to compute the UILabel size from the text string, and move the UILabel so it didn't run off the side of the UIView at the edges. Good Luck!

Comment: I appreciate your answer but i realise that it is so difficult to manage the  label and also the changes with device orientation so i took a slightly different approach to achieve this task. At the end point where i was drawing the circles , i made them as button , had a dot image on button. Then on button click i show the reduce size popover and show the tooltip. It is working perfect for me but i appreciate your effort.

Comment: I found this a fun problem, I extended this code to draw the box around the popup as you had, and automatically size the box and move it around so that it overlapped neither the edge nor the touched point near the drawing bounds. But your idea sounds good too. Thanks for the tick!

Comment: @emrys57 can you please share actual implementation of this. i am confused how to use it.